# Android ActionBar with Sliding Tabs - how to remove the shadow effects

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a screen which has an ActionBar and three sliding tabs. I want to have the ActionBar and the sliding tabs to have the same color and not have any demarcation between them. But the tabs seems to have a shadow effect. I would like to remove it.
I am using AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar theme

[image](http://pho.to/9Yt7Z/xg)

My xml for the screen is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#77CB59"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And my java class for this screen

```
public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#77CB59")));

        // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter 
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                HomeScreen.this));

        // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_start_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: this shadow effect comes from your `ActionBar`, but not from `Tablayout`.

Comment: okay, then how to get rid of it from ActionBar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1, customize your app theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/app_color_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/app_color_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/app_color_accent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

2, customize your `Toolbar`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="center"

    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle"
    android:title="@string/app_name">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

3, replace `ActionBar` by `Toolbar`:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
//If you want to set your new ActionBar
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.arrow_left);
toolbar.setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```